# Can we predict 2D output in CNN?

Tags: keras, input, output, conv-neural-network

I'm currently implementing a CNN model (2D convolution) to predict the distance matrix of a nucleotides sequence. The input is n*n*22 where n is the length of the sequence and the output is n*n where the output is the pairwise distances between two nucleotides (it's a symmetric matrix)

Comment: CNN is used to extract feature u can try it yes, or just flatten matrix and apply simple neural network, just try both approach